# Bootstrap text-center is not working on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been trying to center these 2 buttons in bootstrap for some time now. I found out there is already a bootstrap css class called "text-center" so I'm trying to use that but unfortunately no matter where I use it, it doesn't change anything.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The code is in a form, which is in a well, and if you need any more information let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Working fine for me: http://www.bootply.com/oxhokiXvSU

Comment: Works for me, show us a screen shot.

Comment: @APAD1 they aren't quite exactly centered though.  Still off the the left of center

Comment: Yeah, because you have them inside of a 10-column. If you want them to be centered in the browser then you should be using the full 12 columns.

Comment: use the <center> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works once you include the bootstrap css file (see below). You may have other code affecting this section of your page- try checking your browser console to see what styles are overriding your intended styling.

Also you need to use an offset value to 'center' your col-sm-10 if you do not want to use col-sm-12

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: So I noticed an odd reaction when i click the submit button when I'm on IE or Chrome. Starting off the buttons are too the left but once clicked they move to the center, but gets reset back to left when you re-compile

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate that on Chrome - have you checked your browser console to see if anything else if effecting these elements?

Comment: Im not to fluent with using the browser console but the only error i get is with something called ZeroClipboard which is in doc.min.js nd gives me a 404 not found error.

Comment: I couldnt find any errors in the console so i decided to just validate my HTML code and now it works so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.center-block` class it is the best way to centering an element in bootstrap framework

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10 center-block">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have form-group outside the columns?